# Vertically align text at center - top of an image?

Tags: html, css

I want to the text on image at position center. Like this:

```
     TEXT    
---------------
-             -
-    IMAGE    -
-             -
---------------
```

My HMTL code like this:

```html
<a href="https://hippoxd.sharengay.com">
  <span>Share Ngay</span>
  <img src="https://sharengay.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/forum-moi-cua-sharengay.png">
</a>
```

Comment: try this `a span {
  display: block;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to do this using css

```css
.main {
 width: 100px
}

.main a span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<a href="https://hippoxd.sharengay.com">
  <span>Share Ngay</span>
  <img src="https://sharengay.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/forum-moi-cua-sharengay.png">
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this ..

```css
a span { display: block; }
```

```html
<a href="https://hippoxd.sharengay.com">
  <span>Share Ngay</span>
  <img src="https://sharengay.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/forum-moi-cua-sharengay.png">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `div` and `text-align: center`

```html
<a href="https://hippoxd.sharengay.com">
  <div style="text-align: center">Share Ngay</div>
  <div style="text-align: center"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg"></div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://hippoxd.sharengay.com">
  <span>Share Ngay</span>
  <img src="https://sharengay.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/forum-moi-cua-sharengay.png">
</a>
```

Check this one

Answer (score 0):

Try the following CSS.

```
a{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
 }

 span{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 }
```

But if you want to be more elegant. Try **`<figure>`** and **`<figcaption>`** from **HTML5**

Use this as reference: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/